# How To Deploy: Installing Mezzanine Theme

Tags: themes, customization, mezzanine, pythonanywhere

How to install Mezzanine Theme exactly, step-by-step?

E.g., [Moderna free theme](https://github.com/thecodinghouse/mezzanine-themes).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Preconditions:**

0) Versioning

```
Python 2.7.6.
Django 1.6.10
Mezzanine 3.1.10
Moderna v.? (static content)
```

1) I used [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) for hosting

2) I followed this way to install Mezzanine: [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574508/how-to-deploy-mezzanine-mysql), at the bottom there are links to PythonAnywhere specific guides

3) So, initial state is: Mezzanine is deployed, empty, with default theme.

4) [optional] Basic templates are collected (~80 of them it was)

5) Static is collected via `python manage.py collectstatic`

**1. Add moderna to project**

That's a simple step.

- You should go to site with theme (for moderna it's [here](https://github.com/thecodinghouse/mezzanine-themes) ) and download it. It will be a Django App, probably zipped into archive.
- If app is zipped, unzip it.
- Move it to your Mezzanine project folder (the one, which got created by command `mezzanine-project myproject`)
- Folder structure should become:

  ```
  myproject/
  +-deploy/
  +-static/
  +-templates/    [in case you chose to collect them]
  +-moderna/      [our new theme]
  |
  +-__init__.py
  +-settings.py
  +-urls.py
  +-manage.py
  +-wsgi.py
  |
  +-[some other things]
  ```

**2. Change settings.py**

- open settings.py of your Mezzanine project
- add moderna/templates to TEMPLATE_DIRS in settings.py 1st recor. The point is to give new directions to template loaders - now they 1st look for templates in moderna. Should now look like this:

  ```
  TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
      os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "moderna/templates"),
      os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "templates"),
  )
  ```
- add moderna app to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py above all (I presume, that's for Moderna's views, models etc. - backend for templates)

**3. New Static Files**

- collectstatic again - now it will grab moderna's static

**4. URLConf**

- in urls.py, use DIRECT_TO_TEMPLATE selected for / (root url), it should look like this:

  ```
  urlpatterns += patterns('',
      url("^$", direct_to_template, {"template": "index.html"}, name="home"),
  ("^", include("mezzanine.urls")),
  ...
  ```

**5. Reload**

I *guess* some servers would pick up new settings and urls automatically. Those which don't should be reloaded manually to catch up and start showing your beautiful new theme.

**6. Customization begins**

- Now you can start customizing Moderna theme via `base.html` and `index.html` files in `myproject/moderna/templates/` folder.

**Postscriptum**

I welcome any corrections and extensions, I'm not an expert in Mezzanine customization and the topic has many of slippery slopes.

Comment: which version of python/django/moderna is this for btw?

Comment: @conrad, thx. I added versioning to preconditions section. As of Moderna, I haven't found any version_info on [site](http://thecodinghouse.in/) or in [github repo](https://github.com/thecodinghouse). If you're eager to clarify this moment, I suggest you contact the author directly - [@abhinavsohani](https://twitter.com/abhinavsohani).