# Mezzanine theme customization: the new base.html does not replace the original

Tags: django, mezzanine

I am trying to customize the theme of Mezzanine. Basically, I am following the tutorials of [this](http://bitofpixels.com/blog/mezzatheming-creating-mezzanine-themes-part-1-basehtml/) and [this](https://rodmtech.net/docs/mezzanine/a-mezzanine-tutorial-take-2/).

I created a new app `theme`, copied `base.html` to the `theme/templates` folder, and insert the `theme` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` (note, it is in the first line):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    "theme",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    ...
```

I suppose that Mezzanine will find `theme`'s `base.html` first and use it in stead of the original. But it seems not the case; the original Mezzanine's `base.html` is still used.

Did I missed anything? Is there a way that I can trace how Mezzanine (or Django) searches for the templates in order to find out what went wrong in the process?

Comment: Can this be true? Because the first line in `.../site-packages/mezzanine/core/templates/index.html` is `{% extends "base.html" %}`. Also, `find . -name "index_base.html" -print` returns nothing: there is no such file.

Comment: Ah-- you're probably right, I'm getting confused. `index.html` is independent of the other pages but does inherit from `base.html`. Is there an `index.html` in your theme's templates?

Comment: That's right. I didn't have the `index.html` in `theme`. After adding it, everything works fine. Thanks a lot, xnx.

Answer (score 1):

Use this tutorial, instead of "theme" in installed app you should have copied the template in your project directory and write it's name there. For instance
if you downloaded moderna theme add "moderna" under 
INSTALLED_APPS = (
"moderna", ...

The link below explains all the steps clearly.
[How To Deploy: Installing Mezzanine Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024595/how-to-deploy-installing-mezzanine-theme)